# Is it possible/advisable to request someone to place a bounty on my question?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I have posted a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314353/pgfplot-cross-section-of-a-3d-line-plot-poincare-sections) for which I am very desperate to get an answer. For some reasons I do not understand, the question did not get enough attention. I'd happily place a bounty on that question to get attention, but I am 9 points short to do it. Is it possible/advisable to request someone to place a bounty on my question?

I apologize in advance if that is not a good practice.

Comment: Now you should be able to place the bounty ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Just another 18 hours and I'll place it. Thanks :)

Comment: In some cases, go to our [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) and gives us a note, the residents might even start a bounty for you. `:)`

Comment: I started a bounty for you, so you don't lose too much reputation. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: Thanks a lot. That is very kind of you. Just now I have also placed a bounty on it (I didn't see your message) Thanks again. :)

Comment: I don't think that's possible. A question can only have one bounty at a time, can't it, @PauloCereda ?

Comment: @cfr: you are right, only one bounty at a time. `:)`

Comment: Note that modifying the question is probably more important than the bounty. I'm not going to give my email address to some random web site just in order to reproduce your image.

Comment: @crf: My bad! I placed a bounty but didn't notice that it didn't get placed. Also I edited my question with a link where you can download my data file without providing your mail id. Thanks for raising this issue.

Comment: FYI: 1) Editing your question will bump it up to the top of the questions. You can think of this as a *free* way of advertisement. 2) There are weekly and monthly sessions when unanswered questions get extra attention. Be sure to visit the site regularly, and respond to comments. 3) It is a nice romantic idea that a +50 bounty rep. will attract (more) people, but the reality is that your question will most likely be answered by some superuser with +100k rep, who will not care about at all the bounty offered. 4) It is kind of silly to spend *almost all* of your rep. on a bounty.

Comment: If you can ask it in a way which is self-contained, people are more likely to take a look. Especially, you are saying that this is a big compilation. It requires an engine I don't trust, really (but I may be alone in worrying about this) and you  don't really show what you've tried to solve the problem yourself. Really, I think that improving the question would be a better use of your efforts than thinking about bounties. Whether a question is attractive or not depends on various things and, really, I think a bounty is at most a minor incentive.

Answer (score 7):

Asking is free, so you can definitely inquire. Either comment on your own question (requires no reputation if you're the owner), start up a conversation in chat ([requires 20 reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat)) or comment on an existing post that matches your requirements yet you're not the owner ([requires 50 reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)).

Sometimes, with an informal agreement between members in chat, you could reciprocate/repay the bounty offered once you have enough reputation.

Answer (score 6):

It didn't fit in the comment so pasting it here for the question specifics.

The question is missing a few ingredients. First one is that I don't understand the idea of a cross section of a line. It would just be dots. Do you mean that or something else?

Second we don't have the data. So we can't try anything. That means we can't try stuff out. However a similar difficulty arises if you just dump x mb of text file that we can't handle. There must be a balance for some convenience. For example I would not bother to sign up for those websites to download your data.

Currently your second question is answered in the comments and the third one is here [Does pgfplots support "spatial" plotting?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97056/does-pgfplots-support-spatial-plotting)

For the first one you need to make the question a bit convenient.

Comment: Yes. the cross section will consists of points only. I have edited the question with minimal data(provided with question) so that it can run be easily. Thanks for suggesting this!

Comment: Also the given link is very similar to what I want for 3rd question. But the difference is that I want the labels to be aligned parallel to the respective axes but NOT projected into a plane (say xy plane).